# I see borders in high contrast mode even if I don't specify any borders to form input fields. why?

Tags: html, web, accessibility, high-contrast

Even if I don't specify borders, how is the high contrast mode displaying a border?

Comment: input tag have default border make it border:0px;

Comment: @nikita, but these are not visible in normal mode.

Comment: I am not sure check this
https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/16081

Comment: er. that doesn't answer this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color contrast mode gets rid of many subtle color differences and tries to make the "foreground" stand out from the background. Text and form fields are considered foreground, regardless of their color and visual settings. Placing a border around these ensures that users will be able to identify them.